# Using fragments as workers for activity

Tags: android, android-fragments, worker

I'm trying to learn how to use a fragment as a worker for an android activity. I have the following simple xml layout for my main activity:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent"
          android:orientation="vertical" >

<Button
        android:id="@+id/update"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Press me" />

<TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="" />

</LinearLayout>
```

I define my fragment using the following class definition:

```
public class UpdateTextFragment extends Fragment {

public static UpdateTextFragment newInstance() {
    return new UpdateTextFragment();
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

public void startUpdateText() {

    TextView textView = ((TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.text));
    textView.setText("I've been pressed!");

}

}
```

Then from my main activity I simply add the fragment and call the `startUpdateText` method of the fragment using the button's `onClickListener` , i.e.,

```
public void onClick(View arg0) {

    UpdateTextFragment fragment = UpdateTextFragment.newInstance();
    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(fragment, "updateText").commit();
    fragment.startUpdateText();


}
```

The code compiles and uploads to a tablet with no problems. I would expect it write the text "I've been pressed!" to the text view when the button is pressed, but the app just crashes with the standard "Unfortunately app has stopped working". I haven't implemented a class to catch this uncaught exception yet - I was hoping that it may be something obvious I'm missing or don't understand?

Thanx

Comment: First of all, check your logcat for actual errors. It should contain a stracktrace. Secondly, this is simply not how Fragments work and what they are for. Read up on using Fragments and their goal first in the developer documentation.

Comment: Thanks Stefan. The logcat suggests a java.lang.NullPointerException. Will investigate further. Also, why not to use a fragment like this? I don't intend to use it to simply change text somewhere, but as a worker for an AsyncTask so it can retain its state between orientation changes (the above was simply an attempt to understand its implementation). The documentation seems to suggest you can use fragments as workers, but please let me know if I'm missing something major.

Comment: A Fragment is a re-usable 'UI-element' hosted inside an Activity. The goal is to have certain UI parts re-usable, for different layouts. As such, a Fragment has it's own view xml and is pretty much stand-alone. It's not build to start up for a simple task, do something at the Activity and close. If you want workers like that you should rather be looking into Threads and Services. Your Nullpointer is probably `fragment` being null, or `textview` inside your fragment.

Comment: It seems to be the `TextView` returning a null value, although not sure why this is given that it should just be getting it from the activity. I was going down this route as I had read somewhere that it is a simple way to retain the state of an `AsyncTask` between screen orientations, i.e., by implementing the fragment's `setRetainState` method. Seems weird that the Documentation would point towards using fragments in the background if they shouldn't be used like that; they even provide a sample, i.e., `FragmentRetainInstance.java`. Will look into services as well. Thanks.

Comment: The `textview` is empty, because your fragment expects it to have its own view xml.

Comment: Anyone else who may be reading this, may find my initial reasoning for exploring this method interesting [http://www.michenux.net/](http://www.michenux.net/android-asynctask-in-fragment-best-pratices-725.html)

Answer (score 2):

Altough this is an old question I'd like to answer it as I was puzzled why your sample code didn't work.

The reason you get a `NullPointerException` is that you instantiate your `Fragment` and immediately call a method that requires to have the activity injected into the Fragment. The activity is injected by the `FragmentManager` / `FragmentTransaction#commit` method BUT this method does not evaluate the transaction immediately (as from the JavaDocs):

> Schedules a commit of this transaction.  The commit does
>    not happen immediately; it will be scheduled as work on the main thread
>    to be done the next time that thread is ready.

Which means

```
getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(fragment, "updateText").commit();
fragment.startUpdateText();
```

will yield the NPE in `startUpdateText()` (as the transaction was not executed yet!).

By adding the method call `getFragmentManager().executePendingTransactions();` right after the commit the transaction will be performed immediately and the activity injected into the fragment. `getActivity()` in the `Fragment` now returns the Activity it was attached to and your sample works :)

As from the comments below your question: It is true that *A Fragment is a re-usable 'UI-element' hosted inside an Activity.* ([@Stefan de Bruijn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18314178/using-fragments-as-workers-for-activity#comment26875893_18314178)) but also that *[...] a fragment is not required to be a part of the activity layout; you may also use a fragment without its own UI as an invisible worker for the activity.* (as the official [Android doc](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html) says).

So a Fragment is not necessarily a GUI component (i.e. the view in MVC) but also acts as a controller with its own lifetime/lifecycle.